# Add moving layer to chart when device is unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I'm writing a monitoring tool for crypto-coin miners (specifically for nvidia gpus, ccminer) and would like to show to the user in the charts when the device was unavailable. 
I already have the code that registers at what DateTime it became available/unavailable.
I thought about adding another series with it's own Y-axis (range 0-1) that would pop-up in the back, as in this little mockup:
[image: Mockup]

But as you can see, my 2 Y axis(es?) are already used for other values.
I tried googling for "overlay chart C#", "three axis chart C#", etc.. but nothing usable came up. After searching for a day, I give up and hope that there is someone who can guide me towards the right direction?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need another Y-axis.   Just map 0 and 1 to the min and max values of one of the other axes.

Comment: I wish I could've flagged your comment as the answer. I just needed to AddXY the bounds of an Area chart + do the max/min scale of that Y axis myself. It works flawlessly! Thanks a lot for this simple answer. [My result](http://snag.gy/WMAhe.jpg)